# Is it possible to call multiple activity triggers within single foreach loop?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I want to call some activity triggers repeatedly for my azure function app and these triggers have dependency on each other.
Is there any way to call them within a single foreach loop or I'll have to iterate through each activity trigger seperately for the entire data list and then only I can proceed for the next activity trigger?

Here is the code I'm using in orchestrator.

```
List<processAssignmentResult> assignmentResList = new List<processAssignmentResult>();

specialReqList.ForEach(async specialReq =>
{
  var actionStatus = await context.CallActivityAsync<ActionModel>("getRequestStatus", specialReq);

  var assignmentResult = await context.CallActivityAsync<processAssignmentResult>("processAssignment", actionStatus);
 assignmentResList.Add(assignmentResult);
});

bool sendAlert = await context.CallActivityAsync<bool>("sendAlertPostAssignment", assignmentResList);
```

The activity trigger outside the ForEach loop(sendAlertPostAssignment) is getting called before completion of loop process.

Comment: can you elaborate what you're trying to do? Giving a code sample would be helpful too

Comment: Hi @ThiagoCustodio, I have added the sample code.

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();

    foreach(var specialReq in specialReqList)
    {
        var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => {
            var actionStatus = await context.CallActivityAsync<ActionModel>("getRequestStatus", specialReq);

            var assignmentResult = await context.CallActivityAsync<processAssignmentResult>("processAssignment", actionStatus);
            assignmentResList.Add(assignmentResult);
        });

        tasks.Add(task);
    }

    Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    bool sendAlert = await context.CallActivityAsync<bool>("sendAlertPostAssignment", assignmentResList);
```

Comment: It is not working. It's just adding tasks into the task list but not executing it.

Comment: I'm 100% sure this code works. It must be something else in your end